# manipulating columns in a text file in awk

Tags: awk

I have a `tab separated` text file and want to do some math operation on one column and make a new `tab separated` text file.

this is an example of my file:

```
chr1    144520803   144520804   12  chr1        144520813   58
chr1    144520840   144520841   12  chr1        144520845   36
chr1    144520840   144520841   12  chr1        144520845   36
chr1    144520848   144520849   14  chr1        144520851   32
chr1    144520848   144520849   14  chr1        144520851   32
```

i want to change the `4th` column. in fact I want to `divide` every single element in the `4th` column by `sum` of all elements in the `4th column` and then multiply by 1000000 . like the expected output.

`expected output`:

```
chr1    144520803   144520804   187500  chr1        144520813   58
chr1    144520840   144520841   187500  chr1        144520845   36
chr1    144520840   144520841   187500  chr1        144520845   36
chr1    144520848   144520849   218750  chr1        144520851   32
chr1    144520848   144520849   218750  chr1        144520851   32
```

I am trying to do that in `awk` using the following command but it does not return what I want. do you know how to fix it:

```
awk '{print $1 "\t" $2 "\t" $3 "\t" $4/{sum+=$4}*1000000 "\t" $5 "\t" $6 "\t" $7}'  myfile.txt > new_file.txt
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need two passes, one to compute the sum and then to scale the field

something like this

```
$ awk -v OFS='\t' 'NR==FNR {sum+=$4; next}
                           {$4*=(1000000/sum)}1' file{,} > newfile
```

Comment: what is file{,}

Comment: that's shorthand for writing `file file`.  For processing the input file twice.